# Lead Conversion option

Tags: trigger

How to create a multiple contacts if the last name of lead object field contain two or more names in salesforce for eg if i put last name as a "Bosnon, Bonny mankotia" in a last name field of lead object.Its create new contact of Bonny mankotia after lead conversion?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really alter the standard lead conversion process. But if this is critical , you have couple of ways to do it. I am highlighting only one -

- Implement an after update trigger on Lead.
- In the trigger, check for the value isConverted=true.
- if yes, then fetch the **ConvertedContactId** field from lead.
- Using this field, Query on contact object and fetch the contact
  **LastName**.
- Split the last Name by Comma.
- The list of string will give you give you elements corresponding to
  number of names.
- Edit the existing contact to reflect the correct name by removing
  text post commas.
- Create new instance of Contact(s) for other elements in the list of
  string and insert new contacts